# Android download large files

Tags: android, download

I'm trying to download a large .zip file from a web server but I have a weird behaviour, the description is:

- I'm executing the code in the device emulator, API level 3 (version 1.5) with an SD card of 512MB. I start the device with "Wipe data user"
- The length of the size from conexion.getContentLength() is 7012725
- The server address is localhost (10.0.2.2), but I've tried with an external server and the behaviour is the same. I've double checked that I can download the file through a web browser.
- I have these permisions in the manifest file:

-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

The error:

- It starts downloading the file, I can see the text 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 and then it stops at 60.
- After a while, the emulator reboots itself.

Workarounds:

- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635786/android-download-large-file) issue in stackoverflow is working in the device, not in my case.
- About this wifi lock [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629210/download-large-file-in-android) what I've done is add this permission "android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" and then this piece of code, but with exactly the same behaviour:

  WifiManager.WifiLock wifilock;
  WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
  wifilock = manager.createWifiLock("wifilock");
  wifilock.acquire();
  ...
  wifilock.release();

Here is the code, that it's being executing in a separate thread:

```
private void downloadData(){
    try{
        Log.v(TAG, "downloading data");

        URL url  = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/1.zip");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        int lenghtOfFile = connection.getContentLength();

        Log.v(TAG, "lenghtOfFile = "+lenghtOfFile);

        InputStream is = url.openStream();

        File testDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/testDirectory/");
    if(!testDirectory.exists()){
        testDirectory.mkdir();
    }

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(testDirectory+"/files.zip");

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

        int count = 0;
        long total = 0;
        int progress = 0;

        while ((count=is.read(data)) != -1)
        {
            total += count;
            int progress_temp = (int)total*100/lenghtOfFile;
            if(progress_temp%10 == 0 && progress != progress_temp){
                progress = progress_temp;
                Log.v(TAG, "total = "+progress);    
            }
            fos.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        is.close();
        fos.close();

    Log.v(TAG, "downloading finished");

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.v(TAG, "exception in downloadData");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Any clue?
Thank you very much.

**Update with more log description:**

> Hi Chris, I've tried to discover what
>   was going on at first with this log in
>   the Eclipse environment.  Here are a
>   little bit more detail about what is
>   happening (time - action), note that
>   I've changed the file to download for
>   another one in orther to do more
>   tests, but the results are quite the
>   same:

```
00:00 It starts downloading:
V/iPhoto  (  853): downloading data
V/iPhoto  (  853): lenghtOfFile = 7732809
V/iPhoto  (  853): total = 10
V/iPhoto  (  853): total = 20
V/iPhoto  (  853): total = 30
V/iPhoto  (  853): total = 40
V/iPhoto  (  853): total = 50 (round 00:05)
-> Here it stops and the DDMS disconnects the device immediately

03:40 It finish the download (not always) and the device reboots on its own:
I/Process (  595): Sending signal. PID: 595 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(  595): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
D/dalvikvm(  722): GC freed 2193 objects / 135808 bytes in 176 sec
V/iPhoto  (  853): total = 60
I/dalvikvm(  595): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/ActivityManager(  595): Process com.google.android.apps.maps:FriendService (pid 778) has died.
I/ActivityManager(  595): Process com.android.mms (pid 732) has died.
V/iPhoto  (  853): total = 70
V/iPhoto  (  853): total = 80
V/iPhoto  (  853): total = 90
V/iPhoto  (  853): total = 100
V/iPhoto  (  853): downloading finished
V/iPhoto  (  853): thread finish loading
I/Process (  595): Sending signal. PID: 595 SIG: 9
I/ActivityThread(  757): Removing dead content provider: settings
I/ActivityThread(  748): Removing dead content provider: settings
I/ActivityThread(  722): Removing dead content provider: settings
I/ActivityThread(  700): Removing dead content provider: settings
I/ServiceManager(  549): service 'package' died
... services dying...
I/ServiceManager(  549): service 'wifi' died
E/installd(  557): eof
E/installd(  557): failed to read size
I/installd(  557): closing connection
D/qemud   (  560): fdhandler_event: disconnect on fd 11
D/qemud   (  560): fdhandler_event: disconnect on fd 12
E/vold    (  550): Framework disconnected
I/Zygote  (  554): Exit zygote because system server (595) has terminated
I/ServiceManager(  549): service 'simphonebook' died
I/ServiceManager(  549): service 'isms' died
I/ServiceManager(  549): service 'iphonesubinfo' died
I/ServiceManager(  549): service 'phone' died
D/AndroidRuntime(  949): 
D/AndroidRuntime(  949): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
... and starting ...
```

Could anyone try my code and to download a zip file with size round 8MB? Does it works for you?

Comment: Thanks for this code, worked perfectly the first time, on my Samsung S3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just tried this code in a real device and it works perfectly. There must be something weird in the emulator.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. Did you manage to make it work on the emulator?

Comment: Are you using up-to-date SDK and AVD on Linux? In the second tab on the left of the AVD manager, select "Installed packages" and "Update all", it will tell you if there is a new version.

Answer (score 2):

The "emulator rebooting itself" does not sound good.   I would recommend you start up logcat on the dev machine and log to a file... ie, on a linux dev machine something like

adb logcat | tee logfile

Then look at the logfile and see what you can learn about why it rebooted.

Comment: Hi Chris, more details on my original question about this log.